# React change state continuously with while

Tags: reactjs, conways-game-of-life

I am trying to implement **The Game Of Life** using React, and it works...mostly. My implementation includes a `start` button that triggers the game and must keep cycling until the users push the button `stop`.

I say that it works...mostly because I can see that the matrix is developing as expected, but I am unable to cycle the process with a `while` clause. When I remove such a clause, the game performs a cycle every time the user pushes `start`, but I want the game to perform cycles continually.

This is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Grid from './Grid';

class Matrix extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      cycle: 0,
      rows: 120,
      columns: 260,
      livingBase: 0.01,
      matrix: null,
      killWith: 2,
      setAliveWith: 4,
      continue: true
    };    
  }

  getRandomMatrix = () => {
    let randomMatrix=[]
    let randomRow = [];
    let randomNumber = null;

    for (let i=0; i<this.state.columns; i++) {
      randomRow = []
      for (let j=0; j<this.state.rows; j++) {
        randomNumber = Math.random();
        randomRow.push(randomNumber < this.state.livingBase? true: false);
      }
      randomMatrix.push(randomRow);
    }
    
    this.setState({matrix: randomMatrix})
  }

  getNextMatrix = () => {
    let newMatrix = this.state.matrix.slice();

    const getCurrentCellLivingNeighbours = (n, m) => {
      let currenCellLivingNeighburs = 0;
      
      const getNeighbour = (l, k) => {
        let tryCell = false;

        try {
          tryCell = this.state.matrix[l][k];
          return tryCell
        } catch {
          return false
        } 
      }

      if (getNeighbour(n-1, m-1)) {
        currenCellLivingNeighburs++;
      }
      if (getNeighbour(n-1, m)) {
        currenCellLivingNeighburs++;
      }
      if (getNeighbour(n-1, m+1)) {
        currenCellLivingNeighburs++;
      }
      if (getNeighbour(n, m-1)) {
        currenCellLivingNeighburs++;
      }
      if (getNeighbour(n, m+1)) {
        currenCellLivingNeighburs++;
      }
      if (getNeighbour(n+1, m-1)) {
        currenCellLivingNeighburs++;
      }
      if (getNeighbour(n+1, m)) {
        currenCellLivingNeighburs++;
      }
      if (getNeighbour(n+1, m+1)) {
        currenCellLivingNeighburs++;
      }

    return currenCellLivingNeighburs;
    }

    for (let j=0; j<this.state.matrix.length; j++) {
      for (let i=0; i<this.state.matrix[0].length; i++) {
        let currentCell = this.state.matrix[j][i];
        let livingNeigbours = getCurrentCellLivingNeighbours(j, i)
        
        if (currentCell) {
          if (livingNeigbours<2 || livingNeigbours>3) {
            newMatrix[j][i] = false;
          }
        } else {
          if (livingNeigbours === 3) {
            newMatrix[j][i] = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    this.setState({matrix: newMatrix})
  }

  handleResetClick = () => {
    this.getRandomMatrix();
  }

  catchLivingBaseChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({livingBase: parseInt(e.target.value)/100})
  }

  handleStartClick = () => {
    while (this.state.continue) {
      this.getNextMatrix();
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>
            <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
              <div>
                <Typography variant="h6" >
                  The Game Of Life
                </Typography>
              </div>
              <div style={{paddingLeft: 15}}>
                <TextField id="livingBase" label="Porcentaje de Inicio" defaultValue="1" onChange={this.catchLivingBaseChange.bind(this)} />
                <Button color="black" variant='contained' onClick={this.handleResetClick.bind(this)} >Reset</Button>
                <Button color="black" variant='contained' onClick={this.handleStartClick.bind(this)} >Start</Button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        {this.state.matrix? <Grid matrix={this.state.matrix} />: <h1>Push reset to init matrix...</h1>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Matrix;
```

Method `handleStartClick()` is the one I want to cycle with a `while` clause, but the screen never updates when such a clause is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can maintain the loop like this.

```
setinterval( () => {

    this.getNextMatrix();

}, 100);  /// 100 or whatever value works for you. the value is in miliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

While loops block the main thread so they don't give your app an opportunity to update the UI. I'd recommend you use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) or [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/setTimeout) to perform your updates instead.

Might look something like this:

```
const nextMatrix = () => {
  // compute and return next generation
}

const Life = () => {
  const [matrix, setMatrix] = useState();
  const [running, setRunning] = useState(false);

  const update = useCallback(() => {
    setMatrix(nextMatrix()); // update state with the next generation
    if (running) {
      requestAnimationFrame(update); // run again asap (usually 60Hz)
    }
  }, [running])

  return (
    {/* render current matrix here */}

    <button onClick={() => setRunning(!running)}>{running ? 'stop' : 'start'}</button>
  )
}
```

Note that this approach might be taxing on the browser. If you're concerned about giving other tasks some breathing room you could use setTimeout and update the matrix less frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting hang in your screen while using `while` loop? I don't think you can do that in Javascript with long running process, it easily freeze your UI.

You can try to use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to post your logic to the next cycle of event loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is an exception in this line `let newMatrix = this.state.matrix.slice();`.  `this.state.matrix` is initially = `null` and you are trying to slice it!

```
Cannot read property 'slice' of null
```

This is why `getNextMatrix()` doesn't work!

Also, you should use `setInterval` instead as a while will block your UI from updating.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to read about [the event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

If you want to use a  `while` loop you need some way to give up control back to the browser. You could do this with an `async` function and a async wait

```
  const waitFrame = () => new Promise(resolve => requestAnimationFrame(resolve));

  handleStartClick = async() => {   // async allows this function to use await
    while (this.state.continue) {
      this.getNextMatrix();
      await waitFrame();            // await lets this function give up control to the browser 
    }
  }
```

A working example

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
const waitFrame = () => new Promise(resolve => requestAnimationFrame(resolve));

class Grid extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const rows = this.props.matrix;
    return (
     <table>
     {
       rows.map(row => {
         return (
           <tr>
             {
               row.map(cell => {
                 return (
                   <td>
                   {cell ? '●' : '○'}
                   </td>
                 );
               })
             }
           </tr>
         );
       })
     }
     </table>
    );
  }
};

class Matrix extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      cycle: 0,
      rows: 120,
      columns: 260,
      livingBase: 0.33,
      matrix: null,
      killWith: 2,
      setAliveWith: 4,
      continue: true
    };    
  }

  getRandomMatrix = () => {
    let randomMatrix=[]
    let randomRow = [];
    let randomNumber = null;

    for (let i=0; i<this.state.columns; i++) {
      randomRow = []
      for (let j=0; j<this.state.rows; j++) {
        randomNumber = Math.random();
        randomRow.push(randomNumber < this.state.livingBase? true: false);
      }
      randomMatrix.push(randomRow);
    }
    
    this.setState({matrix: randomMatrix})
  }

  getNextMatrix = () => {
    let newMatrix = this.state.matrix.slice();

    const getCurrentCellLivingNeighbours = (n, m) => {
      let currenCellLivingNeighburs = 0;
      
      const getNeighbour = (l, k) => {
        let tryCell = false;

        try {
          tryCell = this.state.matrix[l][k];
          return tryCell
        } catch(e) {
          return false
        } 
      }

      if (getNeighbour(n-1, m-1)) {
        currenCellLivingNeighburs++;
      }
      if (getNeighbour(n-1, m)) {
        currenCellLivingNeighburs++;
      }
      if (getNeighbour(n-1, m+1)) {
        currenCellLivingNeighburs++;
      }
      if (getNeighbour(n, m-1)) {
        currenCellLivingNeighburs++;
      }
      if (getNeighbour(n, m+1)) {
        currenCellLivingNeighburs++;
      }
      if (getNeighbour(n+1, m-1)) {
        currenCellLivingNeighburs++;
      }
      if (getNeighbour(n+1, m)) {
        currenCellLivingNeighburs++;
      }
      if (getNeighbour(n+1, m+1)) {
        currenCellLivingNeighburs++;
      }

    return currenCellLivingNeighburs;
    }

    for (let j=0; j<this.state.matrix.length; j++) {
      for (let i=0; i<this.state.matrix[0].length; i++) {
        let currentCell = this.state.matrix[j][i];
        let livingNeigbours = getCurrentCellLivingNeighbours(j, i)
        
        if (currentCell) {
          if (livingNeigbours<2 || livingNeigbours>3) {
            newMatrix[j][i] = false;
          }
        } else {
          if (livingNeigbours === 3) {
            newMatrix[j][i] = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    this.setState({matrix: newMatrix})
  }

  handleResetClick = () => {
    this.getRandomMatrix();
  }

  catchLivingBaseChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({livingBase: parseInt(e.target.value)/100})
  }

  handleStartClick = async () => {
    while (this.state.continue) {
      this.getNextMatrix();
      await waitFrame();
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
            <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
              <div style={{paddingLeft: 15}}>
                <button color="black" variant='contained' onClick={this.handleResetClick.bind(this)} >Reset</button>
                <button color="black" variant='contained' onClick={this.handleStartClick.bind(this)} >Start</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        {this.state.matrix? <Grid matrix={this.state.matrix} />: <h1>Push reset to init matrix...</h1>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Matrix), document.body);

</script>
```

Comment: Your `waitFrame` function is a novel solution. Neat.